# Remote access and permissions for Cassandra

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, remote

My friend has installed 4 nodes at his server in Norway.I wanted to add new clusters.I have logged in with ssh and password.Later sudo su,and have repeated 100% exactly the same operations as he did.When I go for

```
nodetool status
```

I expected to see status of the node.

When I go for `nodetool ring` I wanted to see all the nodes.

Output

```
nodetool status
usage: nodetool [(-h <host> | --host <host>)] [(-p <port> | --port <port>)]
        [(-u <username> | --username <username>)]
        [(-pw <password> | --password <password>)]
        [(-pwf <passwordFilePath> | --password-file <passwordFilePath>)] <command>
        [<args>]

The most commonly used nodetool commands are:
    assassinate                  Forcefully remove a dead node without re-replicating any data.  Use as a last resort if you cannot removenode
    bootstrap                    Monitor/manage node's bootstrap process
```

Why this happened?

```
service cassandra status
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since ti. 2018-02-06 12:19:58 CET; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 28725 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28802 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I have looked at users

```
cassandra:x:123:130:Cassandra database,,,:/var/lib/cassandra:/bin/false
```

What does this /bin/false mean?I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The cassandra user has no default shell and so cannot attain a tty session.

Comment: @RamanSailopal How to change this?